# How to order by a second relationship in Laravel query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, logic, relationship

I have a bit of an issue that I've been spinning my wheels on for a little while. I have a pretty complex (and maybe not correct - or rather most efficient) data structure that I'm trying to work my way through the logic for.

I am wondering how I perform a query (orderBy) on a second relationship function on a single query. I'm not even sure if that is the right way to describe it, so here's my code:

```php
$players = $team->players()
    ->wherePivot('year_id', $year->id)
    ->with(['stats' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('score', 'desc');
    }])
    ->get();
```

It seems like it should be pretty straight forward, but the `orderBy` clause is not working. The query otherwise works (returns players and their stats). Here is how my relationships are set up:

```
Team -> belongsToMany Player (and vice versa)
Player -> belongsToMany Stat (and vice versa)
```

Each of my pivot tables that have consequence in this situation have an extra key besides the two specified tables, they also have a `year_id`. This is because the relationship is only relevant for a particular year, and I think this may be what is making this more complicated. So for example, my `team_player` table looks like this:

```
team_id
player_id
year_id
```

And my `player_stat` table looks like this:

```
player_id
stat_id
year_id
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient or best way to accomplish what I want, but it made sense at the time of build. So how can I work through this architecture to make this query work? Also, any feedback on a data structure that may work better would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to sort all players (not stats), you will need to join the tables:

```
$players = $team->players()
        ->wherePivot('year_id', $year->id)
        ->with(['stats'])
        ->join('stats', 'stats.player_id', '=', 'players.id')
        ->orderBy('stats.score', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$players = $team->players()->wherePivot('year_id', $year->id)->with('stats')->orderBy('stats.score', 'desc')->get();
```